# How do I use my spotify api token?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, spotify

So I'm trying to build a random playlist generator using the Spotify API and as I get the info from their server it gives me a 401 code. I followed a tutorial on how to get the access token and now I have it.

My question is how do I use this token now? I've gotten the 401 error again but I think it's because I don't know how to order the url?

JS/html:

```js
const app = {};

app.apiUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1';
var accessToken = '[private_info]';

//Allow the user to enter some names
app.events = function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let artists = $('input[type=search]').val();
      artists = artists.split(',');
      let search = artists.map(artistName => app.searchArtist(artistName));
      console.log(search);

    });

};

//Go to spotify and get the artists
app.searchArtist = (artistName) => $.ajax({
    url: `${app.apiUrl}/search/` + accessToken,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        q: artistName,
        type: 'artist'
    }
});

//With the ids we want to get albums

//Then get tracks

//Then build playlist

app.init = function() {
    app.events();

};

$(app.init);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Spotify Playlist Generator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <main class="main-container">
  <section>
   <div class="form">
    <img src="images/note.svg" alt="">
    <form action="">
     <input type="search" value="">
     <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
    <p>Icon created by unlimicon from the Noun Project</p>
   </div>
   <div class="playlist">
    <div class="loader">
     <div class="inner-circle"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </main>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm still a bit of a newbie at js/ajax (this is my first API project) and I've been following a tutorial where at the time they didn't have to deal with the authorization. Any help or resources appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token must be sent in the headers:

> curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Muse&type=track,artist&market=US" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer myToken"

```js
app.apiUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1';
var accessToken = '[private_info]';

//Go to spotify and get the artists
app.searchArtist = (artistName) => $.ajax({
    url: `${app.apiUrl}/search`,
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'Bearer ' + accessToken
    },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        q: artistName,
        type: 'artist'
    }
});
```

Comment: actually figured it out. turns out i had to refresh my access token. thanks again!!!! :D